# If-else without else causes recursive function to repeat

Tags: scala, if-statement, conditional-statements

Why does the following produce the output "ayyayy" and not just "ayy" (once)?

```
def iftest(b: Boolean): Unit = {
  if(b) iftest(false)
  print("ayy")
}
```

I run it in REPL as `iftest(true)` which should cause it to fail on the first pass but succeed on the second (hence only one "ayy"). So why does it act like both succeed?

Is there some sort of recursive "backfolding" in scala that I don't know about?

Comment: It is because print statement is out of if block... so it will print every time method is called... irrespective of if condition...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Is there some sort of recursive "backfolding" in scala that I don't
>   know about?

No, the method operates as you've defined it. Lets analyze:

1. You call `iftest(true)` and invoke the method.
2. `if(b)` is `true`, so you call `iftest(false)` and start a new stack frame.
3. `if(b)` is now `false`, so we don't recursively call the method again.
4. The next line of code is `print("ayy")`, so it prints it out and the method completes
5. We go back up one frame, we now finished calling `iftest(false)` and the next line of code is `println("ayy")`, so it prints it out again
6. Method completes.

Perhaps what you want is:

```
def iftest(b: Boolean): Unit = {
  if (b) {
    iftest(false)
    print("ayy")
  }
}
```

Comment: So it pretty much does "fold back" on itself like implied. There is nothing wrong with the code, it was made to illustrate the point I was trying to make.

Comment: I guess what I wanted to know is: why isn't the first stack frame basicly "thrown away" when we enter the next one?

Comment: Nevermind actually, I get why it isn't when I think about it. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: @user3407764 The nature of recursion is that for every invocation of the recursive method, you go one level deeper in the stack frame. The higher stack frame is left in tact, as is, it isn't thrown away. Only upon completion of the method in the current frame it is destroyed, and we return one level up.

Comment: @user3407764: Just imagine, you have written a very long method, and in the first line of that method, you call another method, and that would cause the entire rest of the method to be thrown away, because calling a method throws away the stack frame! You would be very upset about that, wouldn't you?